# COM - How to create a method that returns a pointer to an interface?

Tags: com, interface, methods

How to create a method in COM that returns a pointer to an interface, this needs to be done inside the IDL file.

EDIT:

How do I implement this within a class:

```
STDMETHODIMP CBlah::get_Something(IOtherBlah** retval){
return m_protectedvar->QueryInterface(retval);
}
STDMETHODIMP CBlah::put_Somthing(IOtherBlah* rhs){
m_protectedvar = rhs;
return S_OK;
}
```

The above is not working. I'm getting the following error:

```
cannot instantiate abstract class with[ Base=Blah ] due to following members:
'HRESULT IBlah::putref_Something(IOtherBlah*)' : is abstract
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[ attributes here...]
interface IBlah : IDispatch {
  [id(1), propget]    HRESULT Something([out,retval] IOtherBlah** retval);
  [id(1), propputref] HRESULT Something([in] IOtherBlah* rhs);
};
```

Comment: @Phill - why did you unmark the answer?  What else do you need?

Comment: You have to write putref_Something(), not put_Somthing().

Answer (score 5):

Something like this:

```
 interface IYourInterface {
     HRESULT GetPointer( [out, retval]IInterface** );
 };
```

The caller will call it like this:

```
 IInterface* pointer = 0;
 HRESULT hr = yourInterfacePointer->GetPointer( &pointer );
```

Comment: trying to do a get/set methods, one to set the object and one to get the pointer to the object/interface

Comment: No problem, use the snippet by user nobugz in the other answer.